# How to prevent syntax error on PDO / Informix DB query INFO TABLES?

Tags: pdo, informix

I'm trying to extract Informix db table information with

```
$pdo->query("INFO TABLES")
```

All I get is `201 A Syntax error has occurred`

The query is listed as SQL on the manual, so I'm wondering what could be the issue there.

Do you have insights?

Comment: Probably it has something to do with [These commands are interpreted by DB-Access and not by the Informix database server](https://serverfault.com/questions/724693/why-am-i-getting-a-syntax-error-using-informix-dbaccess)

Comment: contrary to the linked example I can perfectly execute `INFO TABLES` in the dbaccess cli tool - issue only occurs from PDO

Comment: The INFO TABLES command is specific for DBACCESS tool.

Answer (score 2):

As already noted, the INFO commands are not recognised by the Informix servers at all but are interpreted by DB-Access itself and converted into the appropriate SQL querying the system catalog and presenting the results.

If you wish to see what is sent between the client (DB-Access) and the server, set the environment variable `SQLIDEBUG=2:prefix` and run the program.  When it finishes, there will be a file such as `prefix_12345` in the current directory.  You can then use `sqliprint prefix_12345` to see the client-server communications.

Running some INFO commands will confirm that the INFO statement itself is not sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to linked info from @your-common-sense I was able to retrieve the needed information by running `select * from systables` on the same connection.

The original issue still exists, I'm not able to run `INFO TABLES`, which runs perfectly fine on informix' dbaccess cli.